# Single-word searches in Solr are not accurate

Tags: solr

I am developing an application to search a product on an e-Commence site. We have about 5,000,000 products that we put into Solr index with all the regular fields: title, description and etc. And while multiple-word search phrases work very well (for example "summer sandals" or "golf shirt"). Single word searches are not so good.

For example when I search for "guitar" Solr returns a bunch of product that mention guitar. Somehow, however guitar music CDs, guides on how to play guitars and guitar shaped key chains are ranked higher than actual guitar. The first actual guitar appears on 120th place or so.
From user prospective, I am thinking, if I enter "gutar" I am looking for actual guitar. If I needed guide on how to play guitar I would search "guitar play guide", which by the way works perfectly.

Same problem if you search "shoes". It brings back bunch of music CDs. Apparently there are a lot of such that have word shoes either in title or description.

One observation I made is that these "irrelevant" products in search results have very short titles and descriptions. That I guess raises significance of every single word in there. If you have a title of music CD "French Shoes", and not much else to go by, Solr is tricked. So am thinking is there a way to assign higher ranks to documents with longer text? I would have to operate with the notion of a field length not sure if it is an easy tweak in Solr.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your observation is correct. In Solr scoring, there's something called length *normalization*. It weights a match in a shorter field more than a match in a longer field, other things being equal. To disable length normalization for a field, set omitNorms to true in the field's definition in `solrconfig.xml`, like this:

```
<field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true" />
```

There are several approaches to solve the problem you are having. One of them is use [query elevation](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/QueryElevationComponent) to make sure that specific documents of your choice show up at the top of the result for a given query string (like `guitar`). This works if you have a small and static set of documents you want to elevate, e.g. if you only have a few guitars that you always want to show at the top of the search result when `guitar` is searched.

Another approach is to have a "category" field, which has values like "guitar", "guitar play guide" and so on. Use [Solr's DisMax query parser](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin), include category along with other fields (title, description, etc.) in the `qf` parameter (i.e. fields to search in), and give the "category" field a large boost. Because "guitar" is shorter than "guitar play guide" (and thus benefits from length normalization by default), and because of the large boost of the "category" field, the query string `guitar` should give documents in the "guitar" category higher scores than documents in the "guitar play guide" category.

Better yet, ask the user if they are really looking for a guitar or a guitar play guide. You can show the categories in the search result and let the user refine a search by a category. Or you can ask the question in your site' auto-suggest feature (if it has one), which is even better. E.g. on Amazon.com, if you type "guitar", it guesses that you might be looking for a musical instrument, an app, a toy, a book, etc., and lets you choose from them.

[image: Search for "guitar" on Amazon.com]